# Convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}{(-1)^{n+1}\frac{n}{2}(1-\cos \frac{2}{n}})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm stuck with analysing convergence of this series:
$$\sum_{n=1}{(-1)^{n+1}\frac{n}{2}(1-\cos \frac{2}{n}})$$

Partial sums plot suggests, that series might be convergent:

[image]

I could try testing absoulute convergence, because it automatically proves conditional convergence.

$$\sum_{n=1}{|(-1)^{n+1}\frac{n}{2}(1-\cos \frac{2}{n})|} = \sum_{n=1}{\frac{n}{2}(1-\cos \frac{2}{n})}$$

But I'm not sure which convergence test can I use here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Since
$$\frac{n}{2}\left(1-\cos\frac{2}{n}\right)=n\sin^2\frac{1}{n}$$
the terms of the series are decreasing towards zero in absolute value, hence the series is convergent due to the Leibniz' rule.

Comment: What is the easiest way to see that the terms are decreasing in absolute value?

Comment: It is sufficient to show that $\frac{\sin^2 x}{x}$ is increasing over $[0,1]$. By considering the derivative, $2x\cos x>\sin x$ or $\tan x<2x$ is enough. Since $\tan x$ is convex but $\tan 1<2$, we're done. Hmm, probably not the fastest way :D

Comment: Thanks! (I ended up with $\tan x<2x$, but I thought maybe you did this another way.)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Taylor series

> $$ 1-\cos(x) = 1-(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\dots) \implies 1-\cos(2/n)\sim\frac{2}{n^2}  $$
>   and the alternating series test.